# Problem with preamble?

Tags: packages, babel

I am very new with LaTex. I am writing a book (biography) and that gives me often a error.The errors have to do with the `.bib` of `.sty` file. The "bib-errors" are solved. Now I have errors that mentions that the sty files is. I am dutch so I use `\usepackage[dutch]{babel}`. It looks as if this does not work anymore. Can somebody give me a hint in the good direction?

This is my preamble:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt]{book}
\usepackage{a4wide}
\usepackage{fullpage}
\usepackage[dutch]{babel}
\usepackage{url}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\usepackage{titlesec, color}
\definecolor{gray75}{gray}{0.75}
\newcommand{\hsp}{\hspace{10pt}}
\titleformat{\chapter}[hang]{\Huge\bfseries}{\thechapter\hsp\textcolor{red}{|}\hsp}{0pt}{\Huge\bfseries}

\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage[backend=biber, style=numeric, sorting=none]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{literatuur.bib}
\usepackage[small,bf,hang]{caption}
\usepackage{xspace}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{sidecap}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{wrapfig}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{scrextend}
\usepackage{ragged2e}

\deffootnote[2em]{2em}{1em}{\textsuperscript{\thefootnotemark}\,}
\pagenumbering{arabic}
\pagestyle{plain}

% ==== FRONTMATTER =====
% titelpagina

\usepackage[firstpage]{draftwatermark}
\SetWatermarkText{\includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{afb/Kirjeet_134.jpg}}
\SetWatermarkScale{2}
\SetWatermarkAngle{0}

\begin{document}
\begin{titlepage}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.se.  You can format code by selecting it and clicking on the `{}` icon. But it will be hard to help you without you telling us what error you are getting. And typically it's most useful to try to replicate your problem with the smallest document you can create, eliminating all other extraneous packages/code. This can narrow down the problem quite effectively and help you solve it yourself.

Comment: `babel` errors can often be fixed just by removing your `.aux` files and recompiling.

Comment: @AlanMunn thnx for your reaction and hint. I shall try this soon!